# Can't write to file in "/home/*/bin/" for Docker Alpine

Tags: docker, security, alpine-linux

For the Dockerfile below, I get an error if I try to write to a file in `"/home/*/bin/"` using a command inside the image.  I can use a Dockerfile `COPY` command to write in the `bin` directory, but a `RUN cp ...` command fails.  Similarly, if I open a shell into a container based on this, I cannot write to a file in `"/home/*/bin/"` (the file is created empty, and writing fails).

```
# Yes, this is a deprecated version of Alpine, but I need to do some legacy testing
FROM alpine:3.11

RUN mkdir -p /home/test/bin

# This works
COPY Dockerfile /home/test/bin/

# This fails with the error: 0.395 /bin/sh: can't create /home/test/bin/test.txt: Permission denied
RUN echo "This is a test" > /home/test/bin/test.txt
```

I can work around this, but I'm curious as to WHY I cannot write to a file in the `bin` directory in the `/home` directory.  I can create a `bin` directory elsewhere in the system and that works, so clearly there is some kind of security in effect to block `/home/*/bin/*`.  Any hints....?

Comment: what error are you getting? and where you are running this? i tried on docker-desktop top on mac and able to see `test.txt` with `"This is a test"`

Comment: I'm running this on Linux and get this error when I try to build the image: ```0.395 /bin/sh: can't create /home/test/bin/test.txt: Permission denied```

Comment: Interestingly, it does work on a Mac though, so it must be something about the Linux machine (Ubuntu 23.10, Docker 24.0.5)

Comment: Have you tried doing `docker run -ti $(docker build . -q) cat /home/test/bin/test.txt` ? What does it gives you? Have you tried force pulling the `alpine:3.11` image (`docker pull alpine:3.11`)? (In case it is retagged from some other image on your Linux host).